# How to convert 1 row 4 columns dataframe to 4 rows 2 columns dataframe in pyspark or sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which returns the output as

[image]

I would like to transpose this into

[image]

Can someone help to understand how to prepare the pyspark code to achieve this result dynamically. I have tried Unpivot in sql but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([
(78,20,19,90),
],
('Machines',  'Books',  'Vehicles', 'Plants'))
```

Create a new array of struct column that combines column names and value names. Use the magic inline to explode the struct field. Code below

```
df.withColumn('tab', F.array(*[F.struct(lit(x).alias('Fields'), col(x).alias('Count')).alias(x) for x in df.columns])).selectExpr('inline(tab)').show()


+--------+-----+
|  Fields|Count|
+--------+-----+
|Machines|   78|
|   Books|   20|
|Vehicles|   19|
|  Plants|   90|
+--------+-----+
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This worked. Good to learn from this :-)

Comment: for some reason I am getting 'str' object is not callable error. I had to reexecute  from pyspark.sql.functions import * to make this work. What is the mistake I am doing. I tried from pyspark.sql import functions as F as well

Comment: Cant se how the error would result. Probably issues with your larger datasets. try replace df.columns with a list of actual columns you want this executed on

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [unpivot-dataframe tutoral](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-pivot-and-unpivot-dataframe/) use:

```py
df = df.selectExpr("""stack(4, "Machines", Machines, "Books", Books, "Vehicles", Vehicles, "Plants", Plants) as (Fields, Count)""")
```

Or to generalise:

```py
cols = [f'"{c}", {c}' for c in df.columns]
exprs = f"stack({len(cols)}, {', '.join(str(c) for c in cols)}) as (Fields, Count)"
df = df.selectExpr(exprs)
```

Full example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[78,20,19,90]], schema=['Machines','Books','Vehicles','Plants'])

# Hard coded
# df = df.selectExpr("""stack(4, "Machines", Machines, "Books", Books, "Vehicles", Vehicles, "Plants", Plants) as (Fields, Count)""")

# Generalised
cols = [f'"{c}", {c}' for c in df.columns]
exprs = f"stack({len(cols)}, {', '.join(str(c) for c in cols)}) as (Fields, Count)"
df = df.selectExpr(exprs)

[Out]:
+--------+-----+
|Fields  |Count|
+--------+-----+
|Machines|78   |
|Books   |20   |
|Vehicles|19   |
|Plants  |90   |
+--------+-----+
```